# Internacionalização usando ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Como posso implementar um sistema de internacionalização utilizando a tecnologia MVC da Microsoft? Existe algo semelhante ao Android para que meu website possa suportar diversas línguas? Existe também algum modo de obter a linguagem do navegador que o usuário está acessando, para configurar o idioma padrão deste ponto de partida?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras:

## 1. Usando um Arquivo de *Resource*, modo manual

Este método é o mais simples para internacionalizar sua aplicação tanto do lado do cliente quanto do lado do servidor quanto ao uso. Possui complexidade mediana quanto à configuração.

### Configuração Inicial

Crie no seu projeto um diretório chamado `Resources`. Dentro dele, crie um `Resource File` com o nome de `Language.resx`. Este será o arquivo base para a criação dos outros arquivos internacionalizados.

Escreva seu sistema sempre referenciando `Resources.Language`. Ao terminar, duplique seu arquivo `Language.resx` variando o sufixo antes da extensão de acordo com a cultura a qual ele se refere. Por exemplo:

```
Language.en.resx
Language.es.resx
Language.pt-BR.resx
```

### Uso

Para internacionalizar elementos do seu *Model*, decore cada propriedade com o seguinte `Attribute`:

```
[Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
public String Name { get; set; }
```

Isto quer dizer que para que a propriedade seja traduzida corretamente, é preciso haver dentro do arquivo `Language.resx` uma `String` cujo nome é `Name` e o valor é "Nome" (no português, por exemplo).

[image: Editor de Resources]

Para o caso de traduções diretamente nas *Views*, basta incluir na *View* o seguinte `using`:

```
@using SeuProjeto.Resources
```

Aí basta usar da seguinte forma:

```
@Language.Name
```

Alternativamente, você pode referenciar o *namespace* de `Resources` na seção `system.web.webPages.razor/pages/namespaces` conforme abaixo, evitando o `@using SeuProjeto.Resources` em todas as *Views*:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="SeuProjeto" />
        <add namespace="SeuProjeto.Resources" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Analogamente ao exemplo do *Model*, a *View* escreverá "Nome".

### Trocando a cultura em tempo de execução

#### No MVC4

Crie no seu `Controller` comum o seguinte método:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang, string returnUrl)
{
    Session["Culture"] = new CultureInfo(lang);
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Em qualquer *View*, você pode trocar o idioma usando o seguinte `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Language.Spanish, "ChangeCulture", new { lang = "es", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)
@Html.ActionLink(Language.Portuguese, "ChangeCulture", new { lang = "pt-BR", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)
@Html.ActionLink(Language.English, "ChangeCulture", new { lang = "en", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)
```

#### No MVC5 (também serve para o MVC4)

Com a mudança arquitetural da ordem do processamento da requisição no ASP.NET MVC5, apenas trocar a cultura na `Session` não produz efeito porque a mudança da cultura só pode ser feita antes do chamamento da *Action*.

Não apenas isso, a troca de cultura implica na mudança de comportamento do *ModelBinder*. Por exemplo, datas e números que representam valores financeiros ou notação decimal e científica precisam ser tratados de forma diferenciada.

Assim sendo, é necessário fazer uma sobrescrita do método que antecede o processamento da requisição inteira, [`BeginExecuteCore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controller.beginexecutecore(v=vs.118).aspx), da seguinte forma:

```
public class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    ...
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string cultureName = RouteData.Values["culture"] as string;

        if (cultureName == null)
            cultureName = Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0 ? Request.UserLanguages[0] : null; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages

        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // Veja mais abaixo na resposta

        if (RouteData.Values["culture"] as string != cultureName)
        {
            // Força uma cultura válida na URL
            RouteData.Values["culture"] = cultureName.ToLowerInvariant();
            Response.RedirectToRoute(RouteData.Values);
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }
    ...
}
```

`CultureHelper` é um *Helper* que verifica a cultura passada na URL e a normatiza. Se houver algum problema no par cultura-linguagem, por exemplo, o *Helper* executa a regressão para a cultura mais próxima:

```
public static class CultureHelper
{
    // Culturas válidas
    private static readonly List<string> _validCultures = new List<string> { "af", "af-ZA", "sq", "sq-AL", "gsw-FR", "am-ET", "ar", "ar-DZ", "ar-BH", "ar-EG", "ar-IQ", "ar-JO", "ar-KW",
        "ar-LB", "ar-LY", "ar-MA", "ar-OM", "ar-QA", "ar-SA", "ar-SY", "ar-TN", "ar-AE", "ar-YE", "hy", "hy-AM", "as-IN", "az", "az-Cyrl-AZ", "az-Latn-AZ", "ba-RU", "eu", "eu-ES", "be",
        "be-BY", "bn-BD", "bn-IN", "bs-Cyrl-BA", "bs-Latn-BA", "br-FR", "bg", "bg-BG", "ca", "ca-ES", "zh-HK", "zh-MO", "zh-CN", "zh-Hans", "zh-SG", "zh-TW", "zh-Hant", "co-FR", "hr", "hr-HR",
        "hr-BA", "cs", "cs-CZ", "da", "da-DK", "prs-AF", "div", "div-MV", "nl", "nl-BE", "nl-NL", "en", "en-AU", "en-BZ", "en-CA", "en-029", "en-IN", "en-IE", "en-JM", "en-MY", "en-NZ", "en-PH",
        "en-SG", "en-ZA", "en-TT", "en-GB", "en-US", "en-ZW", "et", "et-EE", "fo", "fo-FO", "fil-PH", "fi", "fi-FI", "fr", "fr-BE", "fr-CA", "fr-FR", "fr-LU", "fr-MC", "fr-CH", "fy-NL", "gl",
        "gl-ES", "ka", "ka-GE", "de", "de-AT", "de-DE", "de-LI", "de-LU", "de-CH", "el", "el-GR", "kl-GL", "gu", "gu-IN", "ha-Latn-NG", "he", "he-IL", "hi", "hi-IN", "hu", "hu-HU", "is", "is-IS",
        "ig-NG", "id", "id-ID", "iu-Latn-CA", "iu-Cans-CA", "ga-IE", "xh-ZA", "zu-ZA", "it", "it-IT", "it-CH", "ja", "ja-JP", "kn", "kn-IN", "kk", "kk-KZ", "km-KH", "qut-GT", "rw-RW", "sw", "sw-KE",
        "kok", "kok-IN", "ko", "ko-KR", "ky", "ky-KG", "lo-LA", "lv", "lv-LV", "lt", "lt-LT", "wee-DE", "lb-LU", "mk", "mk-MK", "ms", "ms-BN", "ms-MY", "ml-IN", "mt-MT", "mi-NZ", "arn-CL", "mr",
        "mr-IN", "moh-CA", "mn", "mn-MN", "mn-Mong-CN", "ne-NP", "no", "nb-NO", "nn-NO", "oc-FR", "or-IN", "ps-AF", "fa", "fa-IR", "pl", "pl-PL", "pt", "pt-BR", "pt-PT", "pa", "pa-IN", "quz-BO",
        "quz-EC", "quz-PE", "ro", "ro-RO", "rm-CH", "ru", "ru-RU", "smn-FI", "smj-NO", "smj-SE", "se-FI", "se-NO", "se-SE", "sms-FI", "sma-NO", "sma-SE", "sa", "sa-IN", "sr", "sr-Cyrl-BA",
        "sr-Cyrl-SP", "sr-Latn-BA", "sr-Latn-SP", "nso-ZA", "tn-ZA", "si-LK", "sk", "sk-SK", "sl", "sl-SI", "es", "es-AR", "es-BO", "es-CL", "es-CO", "es-CR", "es-DO", "es-EC", "es-SV", "es-GT",
        "es-HN", "es-MX", "es-NI", "es-PA", "es-PY", "es-PE", "es-PR", "es-ES", "es-US", "es-UY", "es-VE", "sv", "sv-FI", "sv-SE", "syr", "syr-SY", "tg-Cyrl-TJ", "tzm-Latn-DZ", "ta", "ta-IN", "tt",
        "tt-RU", "te", "te-IN", "th", "th-TH", "bo-CN", "tr", "tr-TR", "tk-TM", "ug-CN", "uk", "uk-UA", "wen-DE", "ur", "ur-PK", "uz", "uz-Cyrl-UZ", "uz-Latn-UZ", "vi", "vi-VN", "cy-GB", "wo-SN",
        "sah-RU", "ii-CN", "yo-NG" };

    // Inclua aqui apenas as culturas que estarão disponíveis no sistema.
    private static readonly List<string> _cultures = new List<string> {
        "pt-BR", // Default
        "en-US"//, "es"
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Returna true se a linguagem for lida da direita para a esquerda, como o árabe.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsRighToLeft()
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retorna um nome válido de cultura baseado no parâmetro "name". Se "name" não é válido, retorna "en-US".
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name" />Nome da cultura (ex. en-US)</param>
    public static string GetImplementedCulture(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            return GetDefaultCulture(); 

        if (_validCultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() == 0)
            return GetDefaultCulture(); 

        if (_cultures.Where(c => c.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0)
            return name; 

        // Se até aqui não foi encontrada uma cultura adequada, tenta retornar uma "Cultura Neutra". 
        // Por exemplo, "pt" é a cultura neutra do Português do Brasil (pt-BR) e de Portugal (pt-PT). 
        var n = GetNeutralCulture(name);
        foreach (var c in _cultures)
            if (c.StartsWith(n))
                return c;

        return GetDefaultCulture(); // Se nada deu certo, retorna a primeira cultura definida no array de culturas.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retorna o primeiro nome de cultura entre todas as culturas definidas.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetDefaultCulture()
    {
        return _cultures[0]; // return Default culture
    }

    public static string GetCurrentCulture()
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    }

    public static string GetCurrentNeutralCulture()
    {
        return GetNeutralCulture(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
    }

    public static string GetNeutralCulture(string name)
    {
        if (!name.Contains("-")) return name;

        return name.Split('-')[0]; // Read first part only. E.g. "en", "es"
    }
}
```

[Retirei este *Helper* daqui](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx).

Por último, especifique um tratamento especial para rotas iniciadas pela cultura da seguinte forma:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultLocalized",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                culture = "pt-BR"
            },
            constraints: new { culture = "[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

### Como posso traduzir os arquivos simultaneamente?

Existe um editor chamado [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/), que é gratuito, em que se pode abrir todos os arquivos ao mesmo tempo, organizados pelas *strings* de `Resource` (se elas forem iguais). O visual parece uma tabela de Excel. É excelente pra traduzir em várias línguas.

[image: Zeta Resource Editor]

Feitos todos estes passos, a visualização da página traduzida pode ser vista assim:

```
http://teste:12345/Produtos
http://teste:12345/en-US/Produtos
http://teste:12345/pt-BR/Produtos
```

## 2. [I18n](https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n/)

Baseado no [ecossistema Gettext/PO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext), a biblioteca I18n é mais robusta na quantidade de funcionalidades automáticas, exigindo um esforço de configuração um pouco menor, mas seus ganhos são melhor vistos em sistemas bem grandes, de elevada complexidade. A documentação é pouco organizada e clara e alguns complementos, como uma extensão para o Visual Studio, recebem pouca manutenção ([eu mesmo precisei fazer uma](https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n/pull/282)).

### Configuração

#### `Web.config`

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="i18n.DirectoriesToScan" value=".." />
    <add key="i18n.WhiteList" value="*.cs;*.cshtml;*.sitemap" />
    <add key="i18n.BlackList" value=".\js\kendo;.\js\angular" />
    <add key="i18n.AvailableLanguages" value="pt-BR;en-US" />
  </appSettings>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <httpModules>
      ...
      <add name="i18n.LocalizingModule" type="i18n.LocalizingModule, i18n" />
      ...
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      ...
      <add name="i18n.LocalizingModule" type="i18n.LocalizingModule, i18n" />
      ...
    </modules>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
  ...
</configuration>
```

#### `Global.asax.cs`

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Change from the default of 'en'.
        i18n.LocalizedApplication.Current.DefaultLanguage = "pt";

        // Change from the of temporary redirects during URL localization
        i18n.LocalizedApplication.Current.PermanentRedirects = true;

        // This line can be used to disable URL Localization.
        //i18n.UrlLocalizer.UrlLocalizationScheme = i18n.UrlLocalizationScheme.Void;

        // Change the URL localization scheme from Scheme1.
        i18n.UrlLocalizer.UrlLocalizationScheme = i18n.UrlLocalizationScheme.Scheme2;

        // Blacklist certain URLs from being 'localized' via a callback.
        i18n.UrlLocalizer.IncomingUrlFilters += delegate (Uri url) {
            if (url.LocalPath.EndsWith("sitemap.xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        };

        // Blacklist certain URLs from being translated using a regex pattern. The default setting is:
        i18n.LocalizedApplication.Current.UrlsToExcludeFromProcessing = new Regex(@"(?:\.(?:less|css)(?:\?|$))|(?i:i18nSkip|glimpse|trace|elmah)");

        // Whitelist content types to translate. The default setting is:
        i18n.LocalizedApplication.Current.ContentTypesToLocalize = new Regex(@"^(?:(?:(?:text|application)/(?:plain|html|xml|javascript|x-javascript|json|x-json))(?:\s*;.*)?)$");

        // Change the types of async postback blocks that are localized
        i18n.LocalizedApplication.Current.AsyncPostbackTypesToTranslate = "updatePanel,scriptStartupBlock,pageTitle";
    }
}
```

### Uso

#### Em *Views*

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "[[[Index]]]";
}

<h2>[[[Index]]]</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("[[[Create New]]]", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProdutoCategoria.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Preco)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdutoCategoria.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Preco)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("[[[Edit]]]", "Edit", new { id=item.ProdutoId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("[[[Details]]]", "Details", new { id=item.ProdutoId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("[[[Delete]]]", "Delete", new { id=item.ProdutoId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

#### Em *Models*

```
[Table("Produtos")]
[DisplayColumn("Nome")]
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoCategoriaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "[[[Nome]]]")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "[[[Preco]]]")]
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }

    public virtual ProdutoCategoria ProdutoCategoria { get; set; }
}
```

#### Em *Controllers*

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "[[[Bem vindo ao ASP.NET MVC!]]]";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

### Compilando os arquivos PO.

Há dois métodos: o primeiro é configurando seu pós-build para gerar os arquivos PO (botão direito no projeto > Properties > Build Events):

[image: Post-Build I18n]

A segunda é instalando a extensão `i18n.POTGenerator.vsix` que gera um botão no `Solution Explorer` para compilação sob demanda:

[image: Botão I18n]

Serão gerados na solução um diretório `locale` com os arquivos de PO dentros dos seus respectivos diretórios de cultura. Você precisará incluí-los na solução para versioná-los:

[image: Arquivos PO]

A melhor ferramenta que conheço para editar estes arquivos é o [POEdit](https://poedit.net/), que é gratuito e tem também versão paga.

[image: POEdit]

Feitos todos estes passos, a visualização da página traduzida pode ser vista assim (assim como no primeiro método):

```
http://teste:12345/Produtos
http://teste:12345/en-US/Produtos
http://teste:12345/pt-BR/Produtos
```

## 3. Usando o Code52 i18n, usando JavaScript

Existe um pacote NuGet que é integrado com o [jQuery Globalize](http://jquery-plugins.net/globalize-javascript-library-for-globalization-and-localization), mas na época (2013/2014) que tentei usar ele não funcionou muito bem, que é o Code52 i18n:

> http://code52.org/aspnet-internationalization/tutorial.html

Pelo que pesquisei, ainda não existe versão dele para o MVC5 (e possivelmente nem existirá, já que o [GitHub dele não é atualizado desde 2012](https://github.com/Code52/aspnet-internationalization)). É possível arriscar a versão para o MVC4, mas o resultado pode ser imprevisível.

---

Para todos os efeitos, eu uso a primeira opção, que é caseira mas que não me deixou na mão até então, e é muito simples de entender.

Comment: Okay Cigano, obrigado pela resposta. E quanto a internacionalização dentro do cshtml, que não envolve diretamente o model? O conteúdo de uma section por exemplo, ou o menu.

Comment: @Vinicius Acompanhe as edições. Estou escrevendo sobre isso agora mesmo.

Comment: Acho que é isso. Se eu tiver alguma novidade atualizo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez , estou em 2016 usando asp.net mvc5, esse ainda é o melhor método para fazer internacionalização?

Comment: @AlexandreLima Sim, são os que ensino no meu curso, aliás.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez , ok legal, o modo 1, se o usuário não clicar em nenhum link, ele pega conforme a linguagem do navegador?

Comment: Se a cultura do navegador está implementada, sim. Senão, pega a *default*.