# Multi Idioma ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tenho uma aplicação em ASP.NET MVC.

E preciso torna-la multi idioma, utilizando banco de dados.

Pensei em duas abordagens:

```
Livro
     Titulo
     Subtitulo
     Idioma
```

OU

```
Livro
     Titulo
     TituloEN
     Subtitulo
     SubtituloEN
```

Porém não sei qual a melhor abordagem, ou se existe outra melhor. Acredito que a segunda seja melhor, pois forço a existência dos dois idiomas.
A principio o sistema terá apenas dois idiomas.

Gostaria de saber se para cada coluna no banco de dados preciso criar uma nova coluna para o idioma, e como eu trabalho com isso no ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Caso não precise ser necessariamente via banco, essa pergunta pode ajudar você: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17594/internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-c-mvc

Comment: Muito obrigado @FilipeOliveira, porém precisaria também de como trabalhar com o banco.

Comment: Não é uma resposta mas, em um projeto que estou desenvolvendo, com conteúdos em vários idiomas, eu criei uma tabela contendo a identificação do conteúdo `ContentId` e para cada idioma um registro uma tabela filha com `ContentId LangId`

Comment: @Caputo, fiz uma alteração na pergunta, com as duas formas que pensei em fazer.

Comment: Eu optei por fazer da primeira forma pois quero suportar n idiomas, mas com um registro definindo o Livro para que todas as variações de idiomas apontem para o mesmo Livro. Imagine que você resolva suportar livros em espanhol. Teria de duplicar novamente as colunas e depois em italiano. A ideia de uma solução deve se pensar na manutenção e crescimento da solução implementada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira mais sucinta é a primeira, com alguns incrementos:

```
public class Livro 
{
     [Key]
     public int LivroId { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public String Titulo { get; set; }
     public String Subtitulo { get; set; }
     [Required]
     [DefaultValue(Enums.Idioma.Portugues)]
     public Idioma Idioma { get; set; }
}
```

Crie um `Enum` para o `Idioma`:

```
public enum Idioma
{
    Portugues,
    Ingles,
    ...
}
```

Você pode começar só com dois idiomas, e ir ampliando o enumerável quando novos idiomas forem cadastrados.

Uma maneira alternativa é fazendo uma tabela de cadastro de idiomas, se forem muitos idiomas e com possibilidade de cadastro de mais idiomas com o tempo. Assim, substitua o enumerável por uma chave estrangeira.

Answer (score 2):

Se você não vai salvar número de livros, e outras informações que não sejam texto. O ideal é fazer da primeira forma. Agora , se for necessário salvar número de livros e outras informações. Acredito que o ideal seria dividir o mesmo objeto em duas tabelas. Colocando o que não é texto junto com o Id do registro. E na outra tabela as informações que sejam passíveis de tradução, como preço, nome do livro, descrição.

Claro que essa segunda solução teria um trabalho bem maior e se a ideia não for um sistema expansível. Onde possa adicionar mais línguas do que apenas inglês e português. Seria um esforço inútil.

---

**EDIT**

Digamos que a estrutura da sua Tabela livro em uma linguagem única seria a seguinte:

```
Livro
    Id
    Titulo
    Subtitulo
    Preco
    Quantidade_Estoque
    Imagem
    ImagemNome
    Idioma
```

Então dividiria em duas tabelas, dessa forma:

```
Livro_Principal
    Id
    Quantidade_Estoque
    Imagem

Livro_Traduzido
    IdLivro
    Titulo
    Subtitulo
    Preco
    ImagemNome
    Idioma
```

Comment: Só haverá campo texto. Porém terá campos que serão imagens também. Onde armazeno o nome da imagem.

Comment: As imagens podem ficar numa tabela própria. O nome da imagem, caso seja traduzido, pode ficar junto do nome do livro e da descrição. Com uma referência para a tabela de imagens.

Comment: Poderia fazer um exemplo de estrutura do banco?

Comment: Sim, vou montar aqui e daqui a pouco edito a resposta