# Resource com banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources

Bom tenho o seguinte ambiente:

Tabela:

```
Livro
    id
    titulo
    tituloEN
    descricao
    descricaoEN
```

Controller:

```
[LivroController]
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var livros = bdLivro.ListarTodos();
        return View(livros);
    }
```

View:

```
[Index]
@model List<Dominio.PUPO_Livro>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     if(languagePT())
     {
         <p>@item.titulo</p>
         <p>@item.descricao</p>
     }
     else
     {
         <p>@item.tituloEN</p>
         <p>@item.descricaoEN</p>
     }
}
```

Gostaria de saber se existe algum outro método, que não seja por if.

Comment: Siga essa outra pergunta já feita aqui anteriormente que deve conseguir:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17594/internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-c-mvc

Comment: @Dante, Mas lá ele não trata com banco de dados. Até o que é citado no tópico eu sei, entra no método languagePT(), que está funcionando. Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma para substituir o if da minha view.

Comment: Mas é isso, se você usasse internacionalização, sua view só teria os <p>@item</p>...Mas já que ele não usa, você pode tentar tratar isso no controller (Que seria o correto, pois a view não precisa dessa responsabilidade) e mandar pra view apenas o resultado

Comment: Mas eu não consigo entender como eu faço o controller assumir essa responsabilidade. Como a view vai saber qual propriedade escolher? @item.?

Comment: De onde vem essa propriedade? languagePT()

Comment: É um helper que me retorna se a session Culture é pt (true/false). Session["Culture"];

Comment: E como ele sabe se é PT ou não? Você sabe ou tem a implementação disso?

Comment: Eu faço igual no outro tópico, toda vez que é alterado o idioma eu altero essa session. Por padrão é PT.

Comment: Talvez no momento da criação do seu ActionResult Index() você possa passar por parâmetro a linguagem que deseja colocar e de acordo com o que passar colocar os valores dos livros em português ou inglês. Pelo menos a responsabilidade sairia da view

Comment: Mas o problema é que a View recebe uma lista de objetos do tipo Livro, a classe Livro tem tanto titulo, como tituloEN, logo a view não saberia qual atributo exibir.

Comment: Exato, no seu controle no método ActionResult Index() você passaria tipo: ActionResult Index(String linguagem) e quem utilizar o método passaria obrigatoriamente uma linguagem...no controle você verificaria, criaria 2 itens (com titulo e descrição) e adicionaria numa lista que seria passada para a View no lugar da view de livros...

Comment: Esse link vai lhe ajudar: http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx Abraço

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você está procurando por internacionalização.
Dá uma olhada nesta reposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17600/1352).

**Editado:**

Com relação a internacionalização do banco de dados o que você pode fazer é:

1 - Replicar todo o banco de dados e deixar cada língua com seu próprio banco. Neste caso, ao trocar de língua, você precisará modificar a string de conexão e tempo de execução. Um possível problema desta abordagem é com relação a sincronia dos dados, que pode ou não causar algum problema;

2 - Outra solução que você pode adotar é simplesmente acrescenta um novo valor de ID para cada tabela que precisa ser internacionalizada chamado "MasterID" e outro campo que especifica o idioma. O ID aponta de volta para o registro pai. O resto da estrutura permanece a mesma.

Encontrei essas informações [aqui](http://blog.dmbcllc.com/internationalization-the-database/). Tenta ler para pegar mais detalhes de como fazer.

Comment: Mas lá ele não trata com banco de dados. Até o que é citado no  tópico eu sei, entra no método languagePT(), que está funcionando. Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma para substituir o if da minha view.