# Internacionalização, Localização e Globalização

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, webforms, localização

Tenho um projeto que necessita trabalhar com internacionalização, onde a aplicação web precisa ser disponibilizada ao menos em **português** e **inglês**, e talvez também em espanhol.

Minha maior dificuldade neste entendimento, é que ao pesquisar por explicações, tutoriais e exemplos, sempre me deparo com coisas simples, onde eu já tenho no `globalresources` com arquivos de *resource* manual que já possuem o conteúdo traduzido. A mesma coisa, foi quando conheci o [i18next](http://i18next.com/), porém eu tenho que possuir o JSON da tradução de cada página. Mas o conteúdo da minha aplicação é dinâmico, proveniente de um banco de dados, que é alimentado por um painel administrativo do usuário do site. **Como posso conseguir a internacionalização de conteúdo dinâmico?** E o processo é o mesmo para WebForms e MVC?

Comment: Pra responder a esta pergunta, preciso saber como você faz para escrever os *labels* da sua aplicação Web Forms. Não acho uma boa ideia fazer isso em banco de dados, porque toda e qualquer requisição vai depender de banco de dados e isso pode causar um overhead desnecessário.

Comment: Qual seria a melhor ideia então @CiganoMorrisonMendez? Sempre fiz meus webforms com labels ou literais de conteúdo, por exemplo assim: Na tela "sobre a empresa", eu listo o titulo, e descrição do conteúdo que o usuário salvou no cadastro. Podendo ter títulos como: Missão, Visão, História da empresa, etc. E seus devido conteúdo.

Comment: Eu queria um exemplo mais concreto. Por exemplo, [nesta resposta eu coloco um passo a passo usando arquivos de Resource](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17594/internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-c-mvc/17600#17600). No caso, você escreve seu sistema usando strings contíguas não acentuadas, e vai preenchendo o arquivo de Resource conforme vai escrevendo o sistema. A vantagem é usar editores como o [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/) pra tradução simultânea.

Comment: Agora, não apóio a ideia de tudo ser dinâmico. A aplicação vai ficar complexa demais e propensa a erros, e pode acontecer de muitas partes ficarem sem tradução. Particularmente, nunca vi um sistema 100% internacionalizável totalmente dinâmico.

Comment: Entendi, pois também a aplicação fica dependente do conteúdo que o usuário insere, caso contenha erros, não é possível ter uma tradução legal. O x da questão fica quando o meu cliente quer o que o conteúdo de seu site, esteja disponível em português e inglês, e como fazer essa tradução dinâmica do conteúdo conforme ele atualiza a aplicação. E de preferência, sem ter a necessidade da criação de duas aplicações. Vou ler a sua resposta do outro post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sei se existe uma solução pronta que te atenda e lhe dar uma realmente seria uma resposta muito ampla. Posso te dar uma solução em termos gerais, algo que já usei em soluções minhas.

Pode até dar um certo trabalho mas poder e flexibilidade dá trabalho. A solução é criar sua infra-estrutura de localização (o termo correto neste caso).

Todo mundo está acostumado a sempre ter bibliotecas e *frameworks* prontos que resolvem tudo. Usamos tanto estas soluções que às vezes esquecemos que alguém teve que fazer aquilo. Se você precisa de algo que não te atende, e isto ocorre com mais frequência do que parece, tem duas soluções: desiste de algum requisito ou cria uma solução própria.

A solução própria não precisa começar do zero, pode aproveitar algo já existente para adaptar.

Você pode criar uma coleção de funções muito semelhante ao que tem pronto mas no momento que for pegar as *strings* necessárias para cada língua é mudado a fonte de dados. Se estava em *resources* do [Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_(Windows)) ou do [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_(Java)) ou em arquivo JSON ou XML ou *flat file*, agora estaria em um banco de dados. Uma biblioteca bem flexível deveria até ter facilidades para trocar a fonte de dados de forma quase transparente.

Em tese não importa onde está usando. Uma boa tecnologia de localização deveria poder ser usada em qualquer circunstância.

Um sistema de cache é sempre bem-vindo em casos assim para evitar consultar o banco de dados todas as vezes.

Se você quer ter uma fonte de dados externa, se quer permitir a sua troca você precisa criar a infra-estrutura adequada para isto. Eu lhe dei a solução para o que você pediu. Se você pode fazer de outra forma, sem dados externos, faça.