# Diferença entre localização e internacionalização

Tags: i18n, l10n

Algumas vezes o software desenvolvido deve estar disponível em mais de uma língua e passar por um 'processo' de internacionalização ou localização.

Quais são as diferenças entre localização (l10n) e internacionalização (i18n)?

Comment: Até achei uma [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48017/91) com o título parecido mas não tem relação nenhuma com essa.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Os termos não possuem definições canônicas e são usadas de formas diferentes por diferentes fontes.

## Internacionalização

Também conhecida como globalização é a adição de capacidade ao software para fazer a localização adequadamente. É a capacidade de se comunicar adequadamente com os usuários de diversas culturas.

Isto é obtido usando:

- Codificação de caracteres que permite usar várias línguas.
- Separação de conteúdo localizável do universal.
- Flexibilidade para escolher o uso de formatação, símbolos, dados específicos pré-definidos e algoritmos específicos para várias tarefas, dependendo da cultura.
- Adaptabilidade do *layout* de telas e relatórios para que caibam texto de tamanhos diferentes no mesmo local. Isto inclui a capacidade de escrever texto em outra direção ou forma de alfabeto.

Existem diversas técnicas para alcançar este objetivo. Aqui estamos falando destas técnicas gerais. Falamos da infraestrutura necessária para realizar a localização.

A internacionalização tem a ver com a maneira como os dados/conteúdos diversos são dispostos para que funcionem bem em todas as culturas. Eles devem ser universais ou indicar em que cultura está para que possa ser convertido/adaptado, se necessário. Um software que não faça isso não foi internacionalizado.

## Localização

É a adaptação do conteúdo para uma determinada cultura. Inclui:

- Conteúdo na língua/dialeto do usuário e adaptada à cultura específica evitando mal-entendidos.
- Adaptação de atalhos de teclado ou nomes (de funções, por exemplo<sup>*</sup>)
- Forma de manipular textos e números específicos:

  - Conversão de moeda
  - Comparação (para ordenação, por exemplo), o chamado *collating*
  - Regras gramaticais (pluralização, pontuação, mudança de caixa e capitalização).
- Simbologia, coloração e formas de apresentação de dados
- Formatação e especialização:

  - Feriados, simbologia, convenções, etc.
  - Números diversos (sistema, pontuação, símbolos, direção de entrada de dados, etc.)

    - Dinheiro
    - Telefone
    - Código postal
    - Documentos
    - Classificadores contábeis
    - Etc.
  - Datas (pontuação, tipo de calendário, feriados, etc.)
  - [Horários](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) (pontuação, fuso, regras específicas)
  - Sistema de medidas
  - Outras convenções diversas.
- Em alguns casos outras adaptações mais específicas são necessárias por força de legislação e/ou regulamentação ou necessidade da cultura:

  - Convenções de [nomes próprios](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) e [endereços](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/) na forma de escrita e recuperação
  - [Variação de nomenclatura de nomes, endereços, propriedade](http://wiesmann.codiferes.net/wordpress/?p=15187&lang=en), etc.
  - Impostos, taxas, contribuições e outras exigências
  - Documentos
  - Controles e procedimentos contábeis, fiscais, administrativos, etc.
  - Práticas comuns diversas
  - Rotinas e fórmulas específicas
  - Censura, restrição/proibição, obrigatoriedade, exigência de transparência, acessibilidade
  - Disponibilidade de informação e etiquetamento
  - Padrões de empacotamento e manipulação
  - Necessidade de certificações e outras comprovações
  - Tamanho de papéis e outros elementos que contenham dados e materiais, tais como *pallets*, tambores, etc.
  - Sistemas elétricos diversos e de transmissão de mídia
  - Serviços e produtos diversos com regras disponíveis apenas regionalmente

    - Bancos e meios de pagamento
    - Telecomunicações
    - Transporte
    - Mapas, buscadores, guias, tabelas (estatísticas, dados factuais, agendas, etc.), etc.
    - Informativos de trânsito, clima, notícias diversas e outras informações regionais
    - Etc.

Em geral falamos de adaptação de texto, mas vale para todo tipo de mídia presente no software (pense em um jogo que provavelmente tem mais outras mídias). Não só para atender exigências, mas também para atender melhor ao que o usuário espera, que seja compreensivo e que não seja ofensivo ou controverso ou de mau gosto.

Note que as adaptações específicas de um negócio não são consideradas como forma de internacionalização. Não entra o cálculo da comissão do vendedor, por exemplo. Entra tudo o que varia de país de país de forma universal para todos os usos. Tanto que alguns dos itens citados talvez nem sejam exatamente parte da internacionalização dependendo do caso. Mas não há nada que regulamente de forma abrangente o que é ou o que não é parte da internacionalização. Existem apenas alguns [ISOs](http://www.iso.org/iso/home.html) que regulamentam certos aspectos.

Existe uma [entidade que cuida disto](http://www.gala-global.org/).

Principal fonte: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization). [Secundária](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n).

[Informação útil](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Software_localization).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

<sup>*</sup><sub>Mas, por favor, não repita a estupidez que o Excel fez :) e que o politicamente <strike>imbecil</strike>correto tem feito pessoas defenderem isso cada vez mais</sub>

Comment: Sobre o excel você fala dele traduzir os nomes das  funções, o `if()` vira `se()` ?

Comment: @bigown Falando em Excel, eu acho que os atalhos também deveriam escapar ilesos em certos contextos. Salvar = control B??? Ainda bem que eu passo longe de MS Office.

Comment: @rray Isso mesmo :D ... Isso já é mais polêmico, mas pessoalmente concordo, Bacco

Comment: `ctrl+s` para salvar é quase universal haha.

Comment: @Bacco O negócio é usar SHIFT + F12

Comment: Pra deixar claro, a estupidez do Excel é ter internacionalizado errado. Primeiro tem que escolher o que traduzir ou não. Mesmo que queria apresentar os nomes das funções traduzidas, ok, mas grave de forma universal e só apresente da língua da cultura selecionada.

Comment: `ctrl+s para salvar é quase universal haha` só não é universal por causa do office :P @rray

Answer (score 11):

Basicamente, **Internacionalização** é a tradução do software ou sistema como ele é para que *fale* outros idiomas, não levando em conta as características dos locais de origem destas línguas.

Já a **Localização** é a adaptação para o mercado onde o software/sistema será utilizado.

Exemplo: Um sistema de vendas, certamente utilizará meios de pagamento e teremos, moeda, impostos, etc.
Neste caso, traduzir apenas o sistema não vai adiantar para que este software atenda as necessidades dos utilizadores. Então terá de ser feito uma localização.

A localização leva inclusive outros aspectos como a forma de entendimento de um processo, que para europeus difere de americanos ou de japoneses, por exemplo.

Localização costuma ser entendido como uma extensão da internacionalização.

Encontrei esta [referência na Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(software)#Diferen.C3.A7a_entre_internacionaliza.C3.A7.C3.A3o_e_localiza.C3.A7.C3.A3o) sobre as diferenças, sobre i18n, l10n entre outras coisas.

Há ainda um outro nome para as modificações de um sistema para os padrões brasileiros que é a ***tropicalização***

Comment: tropicalização, não conhecia haha.

Comment: Se você tiver alguma fonte seria legal colocar na resposta, legal o link, não tinha achado essa pergunta, apesar de ser um pouco mais especifica.

Answer (score 0):

Quando falamos em **localização** temos que entender que se trata geograficamente do lugar onde se encontra. A sua localidade mesmo. Podemos ver um exemplo básico de localização quando abrimos o site do GroupOn e percebemos que ele já exibe a cidade em que nos encontramos para pesquisa. Para isso algumas ferramentas utilizam permissão do browser ou não. Por exemplo, o **maps** do Google pede sua permissão para saber a região em que você se encontra.

Quando falamos sobre **internacionalização** pensamos na ideia de disponibilizar um serviço para mais de um idioma. Ou seja, ao disponibilizar internacionalização, entregamos um produto que pode ser completamente alterado (textos, CSS, calendários) para outro idioma. Um bom exemplo de internacionalização é o Duolingo que muda todo seu conteúdo de acordo com o idioma selecionado.

Basicamente vemos que *localização* e *internacionalização* se complementam. Para mais sobre isso e ter uma ideia mais completa, leia: [Localização vs. Internacionalização](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n)

Comment: Não sei se eu que entendi algo errado na sua resposta, mas no artigo que você indicou, _localization_ não parece ser nada disso que você respondeu aqui.

Comment: Lá está melhor explanado. Eu não citei alguns itens, por exemplo, uso da moeda, uso do teclado, etc... Não significa que o que eu disse (e não foi isso você quis dizer também) tenha nada a ver com o assunto. Os quesitos que levantei se enquadram também no conceito de localização apesar de não terem sido citados lá e quis mostrar um exemplo.