# Customizar mensagem de validação no Wicket

Tags: java, apache, data, java-8, wicket

Atualmente tenho um projeto que está a usar Wicket 7.8.0 e Java 8 e tenho um `DateTextField` em que sempre que meto uma **data errada**, o `FeedbackPanel` reporta que o: `"deDateField" não é um número válido.`

Eu gostaria de customizar esta mensagem do `DataTextField` para `"Desde(de) não é uma data válida"`.

Atualmente estou a iniciar o `DateTextField` da seguinte maneira:

```
deDateField = new DateTextField("deDateField", new PropertyModel<Date>(this, "deDate"), DateUtils.PATTERN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando falamos de mensagens de validação, seja no Wicket ou no Hibernate por exemplo, sempre temos que ter em mente a [internacionalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98788/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) das mensagens.

Para aplicar a internacionalização nas mensagens, geralmente os validadores indicam qual o nome da propriedade que deverá ser buscada do properties relacionado a região desejada, no caso do Wicket, as mensagens podem ser localizadas no `Application_xx.properties`, que está dentro do pacote `wicket-core`.

No seu caso, o framework está apresentando a mensagem em português, proveniente [deste properties](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/77b4df63f44d00e9350068686e4b091f730f167f/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/Application_pt.properties).

```
IConverter.Date='${label}' n\u00E3o \u00E9 um n\u00FAmero v\u00E1lido.
IConverter.date='${label}' n\u00E3o \u00E9 um n\u00FAmero v\u00E1lido.
```

Existem duas formas de se customizar essa mensagem:

1) Criando um properties referente a página/classe que você está trabalhando

```
Dentro de um arquivo nomeado MinhaPagina.properties:

meuForm.meuCampoDeData.IConverter.Date='${label}' n\u00E3o \u00E9 uma data v\u00E1lida
meuForm.meuCampoDeData.IConverter.date='${label}' n\u00E3o \u00E9 uma data v\u00E1lida
```

Note que neste caso você deve respeitar a hierarquia do formulário.

2) Criando um properties global para sua aplicação

```
Dentro de um arquivo nomeado Application.properties:

IConverter.Date='${label}' n\u00E3o \u00E9 uma data v\u00E1lida
IConverter.date='${label}' n\u00E3o \u00E9 uma data v\u00E1lida
```

As configurações sempre vão ser reescritas pelas mais específicas, por exemplo, as definições dos properties da sua aplicação (caso 2) irão sobrescrever as mensagens padrões do framework, bem como as definições por página (caso 1) vão sobrescrever as da sua aplicação (caso 2).

Modelos mais completos podem ser encontrados na [documentação](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Form+validation+messages)

---

Uma coisa que esqueci de mencionar é que o `${label}` será substituído pelo `label` do seu campo, então você vai precisar também ajustar ele para que a mensagem fique de acordo com suas expectativas.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Era mais fácil do que pensei, para o meu caso bastou respeitar a hierarquia do formulario.