# Classe Static ou Resource?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Quero abstrair as frases/palavras frequentemente usadas no meu projeto, no entanto, surgiu a dúvidas onde colocá-las `Static Class` ou criar um `Resource`? Qual a recomendação de melhores práticas e performance?

**Obs:** Este projeto não será multilinguagem.

**Ex:**

```
public Static class Mensagem
    {
        public const string Ok = "OK";
        public const string Cancelar = "Cancelar";
    }
```

**Ex:**

```
<data name="OK" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>OK</value>
</data>
<data name="CANCELAR" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Cancelar</value>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se é do seu desejo que essas frases/palavras possam ser trocadas em algum momento, use **Resource**. É o recurso que foi feito para isso, e o padrão de projeto possui vários recursos que podem ser interessantes na refatoração, então pode ser considerada a melhor prática para o seu caso. [Nessa resposta abordo estas funcionalidades do ponto de vista de múltiplas linguagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17594/internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-c-mvc/17600#17600), mas pode perfeitamente servir para o seu projeto.

Agora, se forem apenas mensagens recorrentes, não vejo problema em usar `static class`. A função cumprida será a mesma, embora a abordagem seja um pouco mais caseira.

Em performance a diferença é imperceptível, pois o arquivo de *Resource* é um dicionário chave-valor (portanto, indexado), e a classe estática é compilada.