# Dropdown List vindo de uma tabela no Banco de Dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, crud

Estou desenvolvendo em [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) e estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso criar um **dropdown list** que exiba o nome dos instrutores cadastrados no Banco de Dados.

O CRUD já está funcionando perfeitamente. Utilizei o **Entity Framework** para cadastrar alunos e instrutores, cada um em sua respectiva tabela no Banco de Dados.

Na *view* de cadastro de alunos, há um `input` para inserir manualmente qual o `id` do instrutor daquele aluno a ser cadastrado, porém eu quero que seja uma lista com os nomes de todos os instrutores cadastrados na tabela `Instrutor`, e assim, automaticamente ele insira na tabela `Aluno` o `id` do instrutor que selecionei.

Aqui estão minhas tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo, a *View* de cadastro de alunos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aproveitando a pergunta, como faço para editar o texto no `label`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São basicamente dois passos.

## Carregue os dados de Instrutor na `ViewBag`

Este passo é simples. Pode ser feito assim:

```
ViewBag.Instrutores = contexto.Instrutores.ToList()
```

## Utilize [`@Html.DropDownListFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx)

Na *View*, você precisará montar uma `SelectList` dentro do `DropDownList`. O uso pode parecer um pouco assustador conforme abaixo, mas vou explicar argumento a argumento para que fique mais claro:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.InstrutorId, ((IEnumerable<Instrutor>)ViewBag.Instrutores).Select(option => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = option.NomeInstrutor,
    Value = option.InstrutorId.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.InstrutorId == option.InstrutorId)
}), "Selecione um Instrutor...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

O primeiro argumento é o campo de `Id`:

```
model => model.InstrutorId
```

Se lê da seguinte forma:

> Tendo o model dentro da variável `model`, use `InstrutorId`.

O segundo argumento é o maior. Não é muito complexo, apesar de parecer.

```
((IEnumerable<Instrutor>)ViewBag.Instrutores).Select(option => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = option.NomeInstrutor,
    Value = option.InstrutorId.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.InstrutorId == option.InstrutorId)
})
```

Esta parte aqui:

```
((IEnumerable<Instrutor>)ViewBag.Instrutores)
```

Converte `ViewBag.Instrutores` (aquela que selecionamos no *Controller*) para uma lista de instrutores. `IEnumerable` é uma das interfaces de `List`.

Depois, pegamos esta lista e "selecionamos", para cada elemento dela, um elemento do tipo `SelectListItem`:

```
Select(option => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = option.NomeInstrutor,
    Value = option.InstrutorId.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.InstrutorId == option.InstrutorId)
})
```

Ou seja, na verdade estamos criando, para cada instrutor, um `SelectListItem`, preenchido com os atributos de instrutor. Repare que coloquei cada instrutor em uma variável `option`, e preciso preencher `Text` (o campo que vai aparecer), `Value` (o campo de valor, ou seja, a Id do instrutor), e `Selected` (que indica qual campo vai aparecer selecionado, e que faço desta forma para a tela de edição).

Por fim, o terceiro argumento indica qual o texto da opção vazia:

```
"Selecione um Instrutor..."
```

E o último argumento são atributos HTML adicionais que você possa querer usar. Este aqui é para formatar o campo como um `input` para o [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/):

```
new { @class = "form-control" }
```

## como faço para editar o texto no `label`?

Se você não vai internacionalizar, decore o *Model* com

```
[DisplayName("Instrutor")]
public int InstrutorID { get; set; }
```

Se for, [veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17594/internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-c-mvc/17600#17600).

Comment: Resolvido! Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!