# Traduzir .rc no Visual Studio direto no resource?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resources

Estou tentando traduzir um projeto com o Visual Studio 2013 (emulador snes9x). Não tenho experiência com o tema, mas seguindo as instruções do pacote, entendi os recursos e bibliotecas necessários e onde colocar pastas, indicar paths, etc, e consegui compilar com todas as características originais como suporte zlib, libpng, etc.

Mas não consigo traduzir menus e diálogos; se faço isso diretamente — ou seja, abro o .rc via código ou visualizador e traduzo — dá erro *RC2144: PRIMARY LANGUAGE ID not a number* ao compilar o programa.

Para ficar mais claro:

[image: resource no VS2013]

Se eu traduzir "&File", "Recent &Games" e outros, acaba em erro na compilação.

1. É "certo" ou indicado proceder com a tradução dessa forma, e os
   erros estão sendo causados por outro motivo?
2. Vi que posso duplicar cada recurso com o "Insert Resource Copy",
   indicando o idioma e uma condicional. Se esse é o caminho para meu
   caso, é possível usar uma condicional para compilar o programa com
   esses recursos em pt-br?

Nota: embora já existam respostas parecidas, pensem antes de negativar minha pergunta como duplicada por ser parecida com [Internacionalização usando ASP.Net MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17594/internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-c-mvc), por exemplo. Já li e (me parece) que meu caso é diferente, porque JÁ TENHO o .rc pronto, não estou começando o projeto do zero.

Sinto muito se a dúvida for trivial; como disse, minha experiência com VS é quase nula.

Comment: A inclusão de `#include <windows.h>` no início do arquivo .rc resolveu o erro. O menu foi traduzido como mostrei e os diálogos, pelo arquivo _wlanguage.h_