# Como definir idioma de acordo com arquivo .resx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, resources

Estou ciente da existência dessa pergunta:

[Internacionalização usando ASP.Net MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17594/internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-usando-asp-net-mvc)

mas estou com algumas dúvidas. Tenho esses arquivos de idiomas (terei mais futuramente):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O sistema em questão não dá nenhum postback nas páginas, portanto não tenho como alterar o texto das labels no backend. Atualmente estou fazendo isso com uma chamada AJAX que preenche um array de strings no javascript com os textos do idioma atual.

Mas isso me parece ser ou uma enorme gambiarra, ou extremamente lento/sucinto a problemas.

Existe "a maneira correta" de se fazer isso? Qual seria?

Comment: Vamos tentar de novo. Bem, sua aplicação é uma SPA, então? Você quis dizer no corpo da sua pergunta que não é feita nenhuma requisição pro servidor depois do primeiro carregamento? (A não ser por ajax, óbvio)

Comment: Não é uma SPA. Mas sim, as páginas fazem apenas requisições Ajax (após o carregamento). A primeira coisa chamada no `$(document).ready` de cada página é um método `carrega_idioma`, que faz uma requisição Ajax preenchendo um array enorme com os textos do idioma corrente, se ficou confuso, edito a pergunta com maiores explicações

Comment: Mas acho que se fosse uma Single-page application a solução seria a mesma que eu estou procurando :), então se souber de algo...

Comment: Bem, se a aplicação só tem uma página ela é uma SPA, não é?

Comment: Mas ela não tem só uma página. Ela tem várias (sete ou oito), e em cada uma delas eu faço essa requisição pra carregar os textos do idioma

Comment: Então. E para chegar nessas páginas não são feitas requisições para o servidor?

Comment: Sim, são feitas

Comment: Então, por que não usar os arquivos _resx_ no momento de montar as estas páginas? Aliás, me diga uma coisa: você fala em postback na pergunta, o sistema é realmente _webforms_? Ou você só usou o termo?